# Split command on a nextElement

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am making a java servlet and am trying to make it display a preview of 3 different articles.  I want it to preview the first sentence of each article, but can't seem to get split to work properly since I am reading the articles in with tokenizer. So I have something like:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println("<tr>");
    StringTokenizer s2 = new StringTokenizer(s, "|");
    while (s2.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (index == 0) {
            out.println("<td class='first'>" + s2.nextElement() + "</td>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    index = 0;
}
```

How do I make s2.nextElement print out only the first sentence instead of the whole article? I imagine I could do split with a delimiter of ".", but can't get the code to work right. Thanks.

Comment: Are your sentences split on a pipe char `"|"`? If not, what is your intention with `new StringTokenizer(s, "|")`?

Comment: The article's themselves are in a .txt with the information split up by the "|" delimiter. So the first tokenizer is splitting up the title, article, date published, and name of the jpg associated with each individual article. Everything is coming out correctly, except it prints the entire article, where I just want it to print off the first sentence (s2.nextElement in this case is the article itself).

Comment: So single file with articles separated by pipe char, but within each article what exactly are the fields and how are they delimited?

Comment: So it would be like this: Article Title | Actual Article (large paragraph) | Date Published | 1016.jpg then on the next line would be the second article following the same format, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was change hasMoreElements() to hasMoreTokens(). I then found the first occurrence of a ".". and created an int value. I then printed out a substring. here is what my code looked like:

```
while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        out.println("<tr>");
        StringTokenizer s2 = new StringTokenizer(s, "|");
        while (s2.hasMoreTokens()){
            if (index == 0){
                String one = s2.nextToken();
                int i = one.indexOf(".");
                out.println("<td>"+one.substring(0 , i)+"."+"</td>");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s2.nextElement().split("\\.")[0];
```

to get the first sentence in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("articles.txt"));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String article = scanner.next();
    String[] parts = article.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
    String title = parts[0];
    String text = parts[1];
    String date = parts[2];
    String image = parts[3];
    String firstSentence = text.replaceAll("\\..*", ".");
    // Output what you like about the article using the extracted parts
}
```

`Scanner.next()` reads in the whole line (the default delimiter is the newline char(s)).

`split("\\s*\\|\\s*")` splits the line on pipe chars (which have to be escaped because the pipe char has special regex meaning) and the `\s*` consumes any whitespace that may surround the pipe chars.